# Simple jQuery calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a simple calculator with jQuery.

I can append the value to the screen and when the user clicked the operator the first values are clear or empty.

My question is, how can I store first and second values from the input field to use those values to perform the calculation?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");
  let firstVal = 0;
  let secVal = 0;
  let latestNumber = 0;

  $(".btn").on("click", function(event) {
    let currentVal = $("input").val();
    console.log("currentVal is " + currentVal);
    let val = $(this).data("val");
    console.log("val is " + val);
    firstVal = $("input").val(currentVal + val);

    switch (val) {
      case "+":
        latestCalculationMethod = val;
        $("input").val("");
        return;
      case "-":
        latestCalculationMethod = val;
        $("input").val("");
        return;
      case "x":
        latestCalculationMethod = val;
        $("input").val("");
        return;
      case "/":
        latestCalculationMethod = val;
        $("input").val("");
        return;
      default:
        latestNumber = 0;
    }

    if (firstVal === "") {
      firstVal = latestNumber;
    } else {
      secVal = latestNumber;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The question "_My question is, how can I store first and second values from the input field to use those values to perform the calculation?_" is off-topic for this site because it asks about a feature not currently implemented. See the [help/on-topic] for more information.